# ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript not creating indexes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a custom `IDatabaseInitializer` to install just the tables. This is what I've got so far:

```
public class CreateTablesIfNotExist<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        bool databaseExists;

        using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            databaseExists = context.Database.Exists();
        }

        if (databaseExists)
        {
            // Check to see if tables are already created
            int numberOfTables = 0;
            foreach (var t1 in context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' "))
                numberOfTables = t1;

            if (numberOfTables == 0)
            {
                // Create all database tables
                var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("No database instance");
        }
    }
}
```

The tables are created correctly if they don't already exist, however, none of them have indexes or constraints.

Does `ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript()` not generate the indexes/constraints? Does anyone know of an alternative way of getting the indexes in place without having to manually add them back in after creating the database?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think only EF migrations generate indexes. EF also generates only FK constraints and PKs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have migrations enabled. As a test, if I use the default `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer, the tables get created with all the indexes correctly, is there a way I can replicate that in my own initializer? or does it just do that because I have migrations enabled.

Comment: If you have migrations enabled you don't need your custom initializer. Default initializers use `DbMigrator` internally.

Comment: I'm building a custom initializer as I need to install the database and tables separately.